# SQL Error: Syntax Error (Missing Operator) in Query Expression

Tags: sql, syntax-error

Ok so here my code.

```
SELECT Department, COUNT(*) AS CountByTechAndMP
FROM Course
GROUP BY Department
WHERE MPCategory IS NOT NULL AND Technical = true;
```

I have been trying to fool with it but I just can't seem to get it. I feel like it is something easy that I am just missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY` goes after `WHERE`

```
SELECT Department, COUNT(*) AS CountByTechAndMP
FROM Course
WHERE MPCategory IS NOT NULL AND Technical = true
GROUP BY Department
```